# ClearAllFormatting shortcut (Ctrl+Space) doesn't work

Tags: ms-word, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I am unable to use the Ctrl + Space shortcut in Microsoft Word. When I try to add a new shortcut for "Clear All Formatting" through the `"File" > "Options" > "Customize Ribbon" > "Keyboard Shortcuts: Customize"` menu, I am unable to add any new shortcut. I have

Here are the steps I have taken and the problem I encountered:

1. I open Microsoft Word and navigate to the `File` menu.
2. From the dropdown menu, I select `Options` to access the Word Options window.
3. In the Word Options window, I go to the `Customize Ribbon` tab.
4. Under the "Customize the Ribbon" section, I click on the `Keyboard Shortcuts: Customize...` button.
5. The `Customize Keyboard` dialog box appears, allowing me to assign or modify keyboard shortcuts.
6. I scroll through the `Categories` list and select `Home Tab`
7. In the `Commands` list, I locate `ClearAllFormatting` and select it.
8. I click on the `Press new shortcut key` box, intending to enter `Ctrl + Space` as the new shortcut.
9. However, when I press the keys `Ctrl + Space`, nothing happens in the dialog box. The `Current keys` field remains empty.
10. As a result, I am unable to assign the Ctrl + Space shortcut to the `Clear All Formatting` command.

I have tried restarting Microsoft Word and my computer, but the issue persists. Since I am using a valid Office license obtained through my university's email account, I believe this is not a licensing issue. Is there any solution or workaround to enable the Ctrl + Space shortcut for "Clear All Formatting" in Microsoft Word? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

### Update: 17.06.2023.

This happens when i try to add new shortcut:

[image: I'm trying to add new shortcut]

As you can see all buttons: `Assign`, `Remove`, and `Reset All...` are disabled.
When I change `normal.dotm` file to the current file I can use the `Assign` button, but even then shortcut still doesn't work.

Comment: This is, by default, assigned to the Clear Character formatting, which I find useful. You seem to be following the correct steps. However, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: *...even then shortcut still doesn't work.* Did you try my code to set to your **normal.dotm** template? If you can't do it manually, then you have to do this by running my code. After running  the *Sub shortcutKeysClearAllFormatting()*, remember to modify `CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument` to `CustomizationContext = NormalTemplate`, it will be saved in your normal.dotm though and show the setting value in the box you showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to assign the combine key **"Ctrl+Space"** to a procedure?! This is a Windows operating system default setting for switching input methods for hotkeys/combination key. Because of this, there is no response when you press "Ctrl+space" in the dialog box where you set the shortcut key/hotkey. Or maybe your version is the same as my traditional Chinese version, and they mistakenly translated what should not be translated during the translation process *(refer to my pic below)*, which is why they made the mistake of manually setting the shortcut keys. This is a known critical bug in Word.

If you still insist on using such a key combination, then I'm afraid you'll have to use VBA to do it by the program.

```vb
Sub shortcutKeysClearAllFormatting() 'set the shortcut
Dim kb As KeyBinding, shortcutKeyBeSet As Boolean

For Each kb In KeyBindings
    If kb.KeyCode = BuildKeyCode(wdKeyShift, wdKeyInsert) And kb.Command = "ClearAllFormatting" Then
        shortcutKeyBeSet = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next kb

If Not shortcutKeyBeSet Then
    'where the shortcutKeys be saved, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.global.customizationcontext
    CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument 'or ThisDocument  or NormalTemplate
    KeyBindings.Add _
        KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryCommand, _
        Command:="ClearAllFormatting", _
        KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeySpacebar)
End If
End Sub

'Sub ClearAllFormatting()
' Stop
'End Sub
```

You can see the setting is ok, and it does work in my Word testing.

> 「巨集」= macro ; 「模組」 = module ; 「間距」: space bar; These two characters are a fallacy of the traditional Chinese version in the process of translating to Chinese.

[image]
[image]

### 20230616 updated

Yes! I was Wrong!
[Remove manual character formatting. Ctrl+Spacebar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_frequentwin)

[Clear All Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-clear-formatting-01dff891-ef99-4d8f-8982-d7f05cffc145)

and **Ctrl + shift + N** is set the style, not just the chars.

see also the pic below, what my version default.
I've never known that before. Maybe the version you use is English, the native language, and I've been using the traditional Chinese version. so.

[image: update the code]

[image]

#### default in my version :

[image]
[image]

#### ResetChar

**Ctrl+ Spacebar**

**Ctrl+Shift+Z**

[image]

#### ResetPara

**Ctrl+Q**

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that Ctrl+Space is the default shortcut for ClearAllFormatting in MS Word. I've been using that shortcut, and it has been quite convenient, but it suddenly stopped working. You can see what it says about this shortcut on this link:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_frequentwin
Perhaps there have been some changes in the latest versions of Word, I'm not sure. Do you happen to know any alternative or different shortcut that I could use to remove any type of formatting from text?

Comment: @Vukasin Yes! you're right. *Remove manual character formatting.

Ctrl+Spacebar*, I've never known that before. I'll revise my answer later. Thank you very much. Maybe the version is English, the native language,  and I've been using the traditional Chinese version.

Comment: @Vukasin If you still want to assign to the Ctrl+ spacebar then you can run **shortcutKeysClearAllFormatting** procedure by modifying the `ActiveDocument` to  `NormalTemplate` then it will be saved in your Normal template. I've updated my answer.